# Legacy Spring Framework schema in loaded schema mapping

Tags: java, spring

In a Spring Framework 3.2 based application I'm reviewing, I noticed that Spring's `PluggableSchemaResolver` produces a mapping at run-time which includes many legacy Spring schema. Abbreviating for clarity:

```
w.sf.o/s/ means www.springframwork.org/schemas/
```

and

```
o/sf/    means org.springframework
```

here is the complete list:

```
http://w.sf.o/s/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd o/sf/aop/config/spring-aop-2.0.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
http://w.sf.o/s/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd o/sf/aop/config/spring-aop-2.5.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
http://w.sf.o/s/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd o/sf/aop/config/spring-aop-3.0.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
http://w.sf.o/s/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd o/sf/aop/config/spring-aop-3.1.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
http://w.sf.o/s/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd o/sf/aop/config/spring-aop-3.2.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
http://w.sf.o/s/aop/spring-aop.xsd o/sf/aop/config/spring-aop-3.2.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
http://w.sf.o/s/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd o/sf/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.0.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
http://w.sf.o/s/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd o/sf/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.5.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
http://w.sf.o/s/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd o/sf/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
http://w.sf.o/s/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd o/sf/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
http://w.sf.o/s/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd o/sf/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
http://w.sf.o/s/beans/spring-beans.xsd o/sf/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
http://w.sf.o/s/cache/spring-cache-3.1.xsd o/sf/cache/config/spring-cache-3.1.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
http://w.sf.o/s/cache/spring-cache-3.2.xsd o/sf/cache/config/spring-cache-3.2.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
http://w.sf.o/s/cache/spring-cache.xsd o/sf/cache/config/spring-cache-3.2.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
http://w.sf.o/s/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd o/sf/context/config/spring-context-2.5.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
http://w.sf.o/s/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd o/sf/context/config/spring-context-3.0.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
http://w.sf.o/s/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd o/sf/context/config/spring-context-3.1.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
http://w.sf.o/s/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd o/sf/context/config/spring-context-3.2.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
http://w.sf.o/s/context/spring-context.xsd o/sf/context/config/spring-context-3.2.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
http://w.sf.o/s/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd o/sf/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
http://w.sf.o/s/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd o/sf/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
http://w.sf.o/s/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd o/sf/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd o/sf/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/jee/spring-jee-2.0.xsd o/sf/ejb/config/spring-jee-2.0.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd o/sf/ejb/config/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd o/sf/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd o/sf/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd o/sf/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/jee/spring-jee.xsd o/sf/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/lang/spring-lang-2.0.xsd o/sf/scripting/config/spring-lang-2.0.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/lang/spring-lang-2.5.xsd o/sf/scripting/config/spring-lang-2.5.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd o/sf/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.0.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/lang/spring-lang-3.1.xsd o/sf/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.1.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/lang/spring-lang-3.2.xsd o/sf/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.2.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/lang/spring-lang.xsd o/sf/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.2.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd o/sf/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd o/sf/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd o/sf/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd o/sf/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd o/sf/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.0.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd o/sf/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.1.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd o/sf/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.2.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/task/spring-task.xsd o/sf/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.2.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/tool/spring-tool-2.0.xsd o/sf/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.0.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/tool/spring-tool-2.5.xsd o/sf/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.5.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/tool/spring-tool-3.0.xsd o/sf/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.0.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/tool/spring-tool-3.1.xsd o/sf/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.1.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/tool/spring-tool-3.2.xsd o/sf/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.2.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/tool/spring-tool.xsd o/sf/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.2.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd o/sf/transaction/config/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd o/sf/transaction/config/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd o/sf/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd o/sf/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd o/sf/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/tx/spring-tx.xsd o/sf/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd o/sf/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.0.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd o/sf/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.5.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd o/sf/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.0.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd o/sf/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.1.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd o/sf/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.2.xsd
http://w.sf.o/s/util/spring-util.xsd o/sf/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.2.xsd
```

Creating my own `spring.schemas` and `spring.handlers` files with only Spring 3.2 definitions does not reduced this mapping set.

Is it normal for Spring to have legacy mappings at run-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; it's normal. Each Spring JAR, e.g., `spring-tx-3.2.14.RELEASE.jar`, contains a `META-INF/spring.schemas` which contains mappings for all supported Spring versions; in `spring-tx-3.2.jar`, the `spring.schemas` contains:

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
```

Just sharing after spending time wondering and subsequently reviewing the source code and the generated JARs to find the answer.